# MySql LOAD DATA INFILE failing with commas

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Here's the statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv'
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\'
```

Here's a line that imports fine:

```
1450327840667357185, 1, "This is my text"
```

If the text field has a comma though, it fails.  For example, see this line:

```
1450327840667357185, 1, "This is my text, with a comma in it"
```

Why does it fail?

If I escape the comma (by putting a backslash in front of it) it works fine.  This does not make sense though.  I have stipulated that the fields may be enclosed by double quotes, so why doesn't it accept all the content therein as a content of the field?

If I have to reprocess all the text to quote comma's, it would be a big task.

Comment: You have specified that `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` - why you're surprised?

Comment: Your CSV has spaces after the `,` separator.  I don't have MySQL to play with, but I expect that means it's seeing those spaces as part of the values, causing all sorts of problems.  Try `TERMINATED BY ', '`?

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie That's the problem.  Please make this an answer!

Comment: *That's the problem.* I see a space after a comma in the text field value too... does this space is absent in real data?

Comment: @Akina - By specifying the `', '` as the separator/terminator *(including the space)*, the third value is now read as starting with a `"` instead of starting with a space.  This means that the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` now 'works' as expected; the parsing correctly see the `,` inside a ***quoted string*** and so is not processed as a separator.  Conversely, as written in the question the third value starts with a space, not a `"`, so isn't a quoted string, causing the parser to think there are four separated values.

Comment: @MatBailie Please add this explanation into your answer - it is critical.

Comment: @Akina - I'm on my phone and not yet caffeinated, I only intended to give a tip not a full answer :rotfl:  Please feel free to edit my answer for clarity.  *(I've tried to explain this in the answer, but with weary eyes and weary head)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSV has spaces after the `,` separator.

I don't have MySQL to play with, but I expect that means it's seeing those spaces as part of the values, causing all sorts of problems.

This means that the CSV line is read as...

- VAL = `1450327840667357185`
- SEP = `,`
- VAL =  `1`
- SEP = `,`
- VAL =  `"This is my text`
- SEP = `,`
- VAL =  `with a comma in it"`

---

Note that the leading spaces are included in the values.

This means that the third values does ***not*** start with `"` *(it starts with a space)*, so the  `ENCLOSED BY '"'` isn't doing anything.  This means that the parser treats the string as ***unquoted***, which in turn means that the subsequent `,` is seen as a separator.

---

Try `TERMINATED BY ', '`...

This will mean that the the parser now reads the line as...

- VAL = `1450327840667357185`
- SEP = `,`
- VAL = `1`
- SEP = `,`
- VAL = `"This is my text, with a comma in it"`

Note that the third value now ***does*** start with `"` *(because the leading space is now part of the separator)*, and so ***is*** a ***quoted string*** and so the subsequent `,` is ***not*** treated as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing). Load the whole row into a variable then parse it to separate columns.

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv'
INTO TABLE test 
-- FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
(@tmp)
SET column1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tmp, ',', 1),
    @tmp = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@tmp FROM 1 + LOCATE(',', @tmp))),
    column2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@tmp, ',', 1),
    column3 = TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(SUBSTRING(@tmp FROM 1 + LOCATE(',', @tmp))))
```